# MATLAB Maintaining 2 columns based on column 1 conditions

Tags: matlab, matrix, slice, matrix-indexing

I have  the following sample of data

```
Time(s)    Speed(m/s)
1.2          7
2.5          4.2
2.6          8
3.1          12
3.6          3.2
3.9          9.1
4.3          1.6
4.6          3.8
```

I want to only have the data in the time range of 2-4 seconds. I can do this no problem with

```
Extracted_Time_Data = Data_Times(Data_Times>2 & Data_Times<4);
```

However I will only have the times and not the accompanying (in this case) speed value. I know I could use something like

```
Extracted_Speed_Data = Data(2:5,2);
```

which I could then use to make a matrix

```
End_Goal = [Extracted_Time_Data,Extracted_Speed_Data]
```

And I have answered my own question however what if I used another data set with hundreds of lines of data. I still want the data in the same time range `2-4 seconds` but I want MATLAB to automatically store the speed with its accompanying time.

I hope the question is clear enough, thanks in advance for any help given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logical indexing will do it.

`(Data_Times(:,1)>2 & Data_Times(:,1)<4` will select the rows. Then you just select all columns with the `:` operator.

```
rows = Data_Times(:,1)>2 & Data_Times(:,1)<4;
Data_Times(rows,:);
```

or

```
Data_Times((Data_Times(:,1)>2 & Data_Times(:,1)<4),:)

ans =

2.5000    4.2000
2.6000    8.0000
3.1000   12.0000
3.6000    3.2000
3.9000    9.1000
```